# Compiling OpenCV on Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, ubuntu

When I try to build OpenCV for java on Ubuntu I got the following error:

```
[ 61%] Built target opencv_test_objdetect
Generating opencl_kernels.cpp, opencl_kernels.hpp
CMake Error at /home/dinhvantan/opencv/opencv/cmake/cl2cpp.cmake:50 (string):
  string does not recognize sub-command MD5


make[2]: *** [modules/ocl/opencl_kernels.cpp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/ocl/CMakeFiles/opencv_ocl.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 70%] Built target opencv_legacy
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could anyone tell me what I need to do resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24095/building-opencv-247-on-centos-6/) suggests you need to upgrade to a newer CMake version.

You could either upgrade to a new Ubuntu release, or use a PPA, or build CMake from source.